# How to automate Google Analytics to automatically send reports based on desired conditions?

Tags: google-analytics, automation

I consolidate my GA data each day - manually. Meaning I go through different GA sections every day. Sample data I need (per day) are as follows:

- Visitors
- Bounce Rate
- Location of users

Now doing this every day is simply arduous or tiring. I also need to backtrack during weekends or off days

Is there a way to configure GA to send these kind of reports daily without manual intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question here:

http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/07/29/basic-reporting-automation-with-google-analytics/

I do it on the Dashboard pane of Google Analytics by adding a "Private Dashboard"

Comment: If that works for you don't forget to mark this answer as "Best"

Comment: Thank you @Wolfkin for the reminder. Forgot to click it the next day. Thanks